# Spelling "Yeah" and "Yea"

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

When I read the words *"yea"* or *"yeah"*, each spelling can mean two different things.

- An exclamation of joy, as in,

> *Yea[h]* for ice cream!`

- Assent, like "yep" or "yes", as in,

> *Yea[h]*, Mom, of course I fed the dogs.

The two meanings not only have different pronunciation, but they're also not differentiable using context clues. For example, folks will commonly say *"Yeah"* as a one-word answer in a chat or a one-word comment in a forum.

Is there a better way to spell these so as to differentiate them without context?
Or, perhaps, do these two different spellings have two different meanings, and I just didn't notice?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They are differentiated by spelling:

- *Yay* [ jɛi ] (as opposed to, say, *boo)* is for joy and exultation;
- *Yeah* [ jæ ] (synonym of *yes*, opposite of *nah)* is for ordinary assent; and
- *Yea* [ jɛi ] (opposite of *nay)* is for formal assent during a vote.

It's just that many people type *yea* (or even just *ya)* when they mean *yeah.*

Outside of the U.S., *yeh* [ jɛ ] is also common.

Comment: Yeah! What he said.

Comment: The pronunciation you gave for *yeah* is not too common, in my opinion. People often pronounce *yeah* with a diphthong.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: I was simplifying. I hear /jæ/, /jɛ/, /jeə/, and /jiə/ with roughly equal frequency—and varying degrees of nasalisation—so I just chose one and went with it rather than complicate the matter. Like many of the less word-like interjections, its pronunciation is hugely dependent on accent, context, and emphasis. My interpretation may also have something to do with the fact that I don't merge *merry*, *marry*, and *Mary*.

Comment: Cool. I usually go with the last two: /jeə/ and /jiə/. I also say /jæ/ and /jɛ/, but I'd most probably spell them *yah* and *yeh*!

Comment: Yay! The first answer got it right!